# BaaS to work with Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, stackmob

Is there a BaaS (backend as a service) that will work without modification with Angular.js? I reviewed both Parse.com and Stackmob and they both seem to be based on Backbone.js and I'd prefer not to have to fight against that. Has anyone implemented either with Angular.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look at [Firebase](http://bit.ly/137bXTQ) which play nicely with AngularJS. They created an official AngularJS bindings : AngularFire

Here is a presentation on Youtube : [Realtime Web Apps with AngularJS and Firebase](http://bit.ly/137btwY)